# SQL sum and count command. How do I group my table content to output two groups (rows) of results?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by

This is my SQL table:
[image: The content of my 'sponsor' table]

So this is my sql query:
       `SELECT sponsor_name, sub_name, sum(amount), count(id)`
       `FROM sponsor`

and the output is like this:
[image]

I want the output to show both Adidas and Dell Computers with their own sum and count. So it will show two rows like:
**sponsor_name**        
**sub_name**                    
**sum(amount)**    
**count(id)**

Adidas                      
Food Bank Kelowna                     
9000                 
4

Dell Computer          
Food Bank Kelowna                     
1500                 
3

Answer (score 3):

You should group by the columns you don't want to aggregate. In this case, `sponsor_name` and `sub_name`:

```
SELECT   sponsor_name, sub_name, SUM(amount), COUNT(id)
FROM     sponsor
GROUP BY sponsor_name, sub_name
```

Comment: omg thank you so much! It didnt occur to me, completely forgot about group by.

Answer (score 1):

`COUNT` and `SUM` (among others) are [Aggregated Functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aggregate_function), that means they return a single value grouped somehow (by a column or a set of columns). You should do this by specifying a `GROUP BY` clause in your query.

So, try this:

```
SELECT sponsor_name, sub_name, sum(amount), count(1) 
    FROM SPONSOR 
    GROUP BY sponsor_name, sub_name;
```